# Is it possible to pick specific machines to run a particular type of hadoop jobs?

Tags: hadoop

As far as I understand hadoop architecture considers all machines to be equal with any task/job being able to run on all and any of the machines in the cluster.

Is there a way to change this model to tag certain machines as having certain capabilities and then only pick machines that have capabilities required by a job to run that job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out. Since I am using the FairScheduler there is an extensibility point there that allows me to achieve my goal by writing a simple class implementing LoadManager interface

According to http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/fair_scheduler.html, FairScheduler uses instance of a class specified in mapred.fairscheduler.loadmanager config property (CapBasedLoadManager by default). The LoadManager interface provides convinient method

```
boolean canLaunchTask(TaskTrackerStatus tracker, JobInProgress job,  TaskType type)
```

which allows me to have custom logic to allow or deny particular job to run on a particular task tracker. Problem solved.

Lesson learned: reading source code is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well. this seems useful but the data may not be local right ? One could also run two Jobtrackers, each managing a different pool of tasktrackers. You can submit the job to the right jobtracker.